# Grails 2.3.6 Scaffolded index page throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-2.3

I have a grails application which is failing at runtime in a cryptic way
(cyptic to me anyway)
with a **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** when I visit the scaffolded /imca2/imcaReferral/index.

*** now edited to put solution at end ***

There are about a dozen domain classes.
I haven't got round to worrying about the UI yet so the controllers are all dynamically scaffolded.

All the other controllers work OK.

**This Controller**:

```
package com.ubergen
class ImcaReferralController {
    def scaffold = ImcaReferral
}
```

For this Domain:

```
package com.ubergen
class ImcaReferral {
    private def todayDate = new Date()
    String          advocacyReferenceNum        = ""
[snip a lot of code]
    String toString() {
        "${this.advocacyReferenceNum}: ${this.client?this.client:'-'}${this.referralIssue?', '+this.referralIssue:''}"
    }
}
```

(I don't want to post the domain class here as its huge).

**Produces this stacktrace**:

```
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/imca2
| Error 2014-03-12 18:48:24,935 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occurred when processing request: [GET] /imca2/imcaReferral/index
0. Stacktrace follows:
Message: 0
    Line | Method
->>   55 | <init>     in grails.orm.PagedResultList
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     15 | $tt__index in com.ubergen.ImcaReferralController
|    191 | doFilter . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter   in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1146 | runWorker  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    701 | run . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Cleaning and (re)compiling make no difference.

The domain class is being used during bootstrapping to push data successfully into the database, so it works to that extent.

I can run the application from the command line instead of from inside eclipse/STS. The same error is thrown.

run-app --noreloading makes no difference either (clutching at straws now). And run-war also produces the same error.

run-app --verbose shows:

```
| Error 2014-03-12 19:58:37,745 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occurred when processing request: [GET] /imca2/imcaReferral/index
0. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.hibernate.criterion.Order.toSqlString(Order.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getOrderBy(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:394)
    [snip]
    at grails.orm.PagedResultList.<init>(PagedResultList.java:55)
    [snip]
    at com.ubergen.ImcaReferral.list(ImcaReferral.groovy)
    [snip]
    at com.ubergen.ImcaReferralController.$tt__index(script1394654146228610896735.groovy:15)
    [snip]
```

So the index page calls the domain's list() and this is a problem in some way but not enough of a way that its getting mentioned in the stacktrace.

Where should I look first for the problem?

**Versions**:

```
ubuntu 10.04
eclipse / SpringToolSuite 3.4.0
grails 2.3.6
groovy 2.1.9 (for both project and workspace)
```

**Update 13/03/2014**

I followed Joe's suggestions (below) and found that the problem is indeed in the ImcaReferral.list() method.

In the grails console simply running:

```
package com.ubergen
ImcaReferral.withTransaction { status -> 
    ImcaReferral.list()
 }
```

Returns

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at org.hibernate.criterion.Order.toSqlString(Order.java:73)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getOrderBy(CriteriaQueryTranslator.ja a:394)
[snip]
at com.ubergen.ImcaReferral.list(ImcaReferral.groovy)
```

Looking at the domain's sort order information **BINGO!** its incorrectly defined, there are two competing definitions of how to sort the domain.

I Comment out the erroneous sort order information:

```
package com.ubergen
class ImcaReferral {
    ...
    static hasMany = [challenges:Challenge]
    static mapping = {
         ...
         sort dateReceived:'asc' 
      // sort challenges:'challengeRoute'   // *** ERROR ***
    }
}
```

and (after restarting the console) the call to list works fine and returns an empty array.

Correcting the sort order of the child records:

```
package com.ubergen
class ImcaReferral {
    ...
    static hasMany = [challenges:Challenge]
    static mapping = {
        ...
        sort dateReceived:'asc' 
        challenges sort: 'challengeRoute', order: 'asc' // *** CORRECT ***
    }
}
```

Fixes the problem. The scaffolding now works.

**Conclusions**

1. Trust the full stacktrace even if its rather verbose. It shows the classes and methods to look at.
2. Learn to use the console.

   grails -reloading console
3. Read your more code carefully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to generate the Static Scaffolding and see if you get a different result.  You could also try running the list in a integration test to see what happens.

Comment: I _am_ using Dynamic Scaffolding - because I just want something 'quick and painless' at this stage.

Generating the static scaffolding produces exactly the same result.

I will try an integration test on list().

Comment: There is indeed a problem with the list method on my domain class. Its something to do with the sort order.

Using the Console I can run the domain's count() and it returns 0. But if I run the domain's list() it throws:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

at org.hibernate.criterion.Order.toSqlString(Order.java:73)

Comment: Try removing your Static Mappings from the Domain class and try again?

Comment: There were two definitions of how to sort the domain. One was a garbled attempt to sort the domains 'hasMany' children. This meant that the attempt to build the query failed at runtime, which meant the list() failed, which meant the scaffolding failed.